# Php loop with 1 show and hide in div function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm kinda new to this and i also apologize if i made it unclear what i am trying to do.

In my database i have 2 images and info about leg armor wich if i click on the corrosponding div shows a overlay:

```
    <div class="legs">
       <a id="legs" onclick="legShow();"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="LegItems" >

<?php
$sqlleg = "SELECT * FROM items
WHERE part = 'legs'";
$legquery = mysqli_query($con, $sqlleg) or die (mysqli_error($con));

$rowleg = mysqli_fetch_row($legquery);


while($legf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($legquery))
{
?>
    <img id="legArmor" src="<?php echo $legf['image']; ?>" onclick="legHide()"/>
<?php
}
?>
```

And the functions:

```
    <script>

function legShow() {
                var LegItems = document.getElementById('LegItems');
                LegItems.style.display = 'block';
                LegItems.style.z-index = 400;
}

function legHide() {
                var legs = document.getElementById("legs");
                var LegItems = document.getElementById('LegItems');
                LegItems.style.display = 'none';
                legs.innerHTML = "<img src='<?php echo $legf['image']; ?>' width=80; height=120;>"

}


</script>
```

Problems are: 
When i click on the leg div the overlay does open but i only see 1 image instead of 2. (only the last one)

Second problem is that the leg div is a empty square that if clicked opens the overlay with the leg pictures. I want the leg picture that i click to fill the empty square.

I apologize again if its not clear. (I'm dutch :D)

Comment: IDs have to be unique. All your images have the same ID `legArmor`.

Comment: I tried removing the ID from the images but i still only get 1. 
The ID is only there to make the images have a certain height and width.

Comment: If you mean it's there for CSS, use a class, not an ID.

Comment: If you're having two problems, it's best to do them in different questions. It's unreasonable to expect the same person to solve both problems.

Comment: Looking at it yes a class would be better.
I'm not expecting anything from anyone. If someone can help me with both that would be nice if not too bad. But making 2 topics seems to only make it harder since the second problem has to work with the first one.

Comment: If someone answers part 1, and a different person answers part 2, which one will you accept? You can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try commenting this line

```
$rowleg = mysqli_fetch_row($legquery);
```

this line moves the pointer to next row which results only the last image to be shown. 
I didn't quite get what you mean in your second problem. 
Also use id's only once. if you need to use multiple you can always use legArmor[0],legArmor[1] etc

Comment: I'm really new to this so i make alot of starter mistakes.
Also trying to make the second problem more understanding:
I actually want the picture i click in the overlay to fill the empty leg div.

Comment: First wasnt sure what commenting meant but i got it now thanks that fixed it